# Error message "You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure"

Tags: youtube-api

I am developing a web-based application that will allow my trusted staff to edit the titles, descriptions, tags, etc. of my YouTube channel. In attempting to "Opt In" to my own application, I was sent to the callback URI with an error message:

> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.

Some history - when I first attempted to obtain a code to exchange to an authorization token, it actually worked! However, as I was writing the code to harvest the code and exchange it for the authorization token, I repeated the "Opt In" process multiple times. Before I was ever able to perfect my code to exchange the code for an authorization token, I began getting the error message to the effect that the app is insecure and cannot be signed in to.

More history - after reading a Stack Overflow article describing something similar, I *deleted* the project, created a new project, generated a new Client ID and Client Secret, and then repeated the test with the same failure.

I am the only Test User of the app. I can't find any notification in my console alerting me to nature of the security issue triggering the failures. I have reviewed the OAuth policies at

*[OAuth 2.0 Policies](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies?hl=en)*

and cannot find anything even remotely wrong.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12):

I also had the same issue.

For me, it turned out that my `redirect_uri` is not valid. The `redirect_uri` that gives error:

```
http://localhost:8000api/vi/oauth/google
```

What are wrong in my case:

- I should put a `/` before `api`.
- `vi` is different from what I registered on GCP. It should be `v1`

I would suggest you to print out the `redirect_uri` when your app is performing code exchange, and verify every single characters carefully.

Additionally, check out the documentation of [Redirect URI validation rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation) on Google to see if your `redirect_uri` comply with all the rules.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the trailing `/ ` which is required.

Answer (score 1):

You probably changed the port where the project is running or you did not define the address where the project is running in [Google Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform).

Google Cloud → *APIs and Services* → *Credentials* → *OAuth 2 Client ID* → change  *Authorized JavaScript origin* to the port that your app runs on the local or shared host.

The URL may take time to define, so it may not work right away, so you can also create a new credential.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the "Authorized js origin "? Can Anybody see it?

Answer (score 0):

For me the redirect_uri was correct, but as a result of an error, the access code was requested for a different client ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase with react native expo like i did and got this error what you need to do is copy your web client ID from firebase and paste it next too
[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/[Web](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/%5BWeb) Client ID from firebase]

this will open the auth generated oauth client by firebase there you will see under Authorized redirect the url https://appname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

then in your code for react native expo

`const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest( { clientId: 'client ID from firebase', // web client id from firebase scopes: ['profile', 'email'], // what the app is requesting access to from gmail redirectUri: 'https://appname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler',// the redirect url that the user will be directed back to after auth with google  },`

this should fix the error for me but of course there is more code to add the reason you get this error is because you need to set the same redirect uri as in the gcp in the code i hope this helps someone one day