# Get e-mail with Google API and PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

## The problem

I'm trying to get the e-mail of a user with the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server).
I want to do it using cURL and PHP.

So basically:
=>  You click on a button, you're redirected to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth + scope + access_type etc.
=> Once you choosed your account, you're redirected to the new page, and it's in this page that I have the problem.

## What I tried

Searching on Stack Overflow and modifying my code but nothing worked. Also, I didn't find anything apart from:  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70638732/you-cant-sign-in-to-this-app-because-it-doesnt-comply-with-googles-oauth) 
But there is no solution and it's not really the same problem

The error is

```html
Array
(
    [error] => invalid_request
    [error_description] =>  You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
  
)
```

So I look at the "Google validation rules":
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation
And, I think that my code respects all theses rules.

## Show some code

Note:
`$google_id` and `$google_secret` are defined earlier with the correct values.

```php
$code = $_GET["code"];

if (!isset($code)) exit();

# The url oauth2 google API
$url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

# The data you want to send via POST
$redirect_uri = urlencode("http://localhost:9000/loginWithGoogleProcess.php"); # redirect_uri
$fields = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $google_id,
    'client_secret' => $google_secret,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => "authorization_code"
);

# Convert array to string URL
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);



# Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

# Set basic options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

# Curl SSL
# If there is not these lines here, the response will be false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

# So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

# Execute post
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


print_r($result);
```

And what results from print_r is :

```html
Array
(
    [error] => invalid_request
    [error_description] =>  You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure. You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
  
)
```

Comment: http://localhost:9000/loginWithGoogleProcess.php  <-- https

Comment: @DaImTo Sadly no. As said in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation
"Redirect URIs must use the HTTPS scheme, not plain HTTP. Localhost URIs (including localhost IP address URIs) are exempt from this rule."